# ScaleLine shows NaN for LCC projection

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, coordinate-system, scale

I have used openlayers along with geoserver. My Map is having LCC projection by default, but SRS is `EPSG:4042`.

The problem is that the scaleline shows NaN in meter as well as feet. How can I correct it?

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
    66.76242541918388, 6.756367055683252,
    98.64805108111362, 37.558217731396034
);

var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
    {
        maxExtent: bounds,
        maxResolution: 0.10,
        projection: "EPSG:4042",
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(79, 21)
     }
);
```

EDIT 1 :
This happens only when I give a projection for `OpenLayers.Map`. Otherwise, the scale is correct.

EDIT 2: This worked for me:

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
    66.76242541918388, 6.756367055683252,
    98.64805108111362, 37.558217731396034
);

var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
    {
        maxExtent: bounds,
        maxResolution: 0.10,
        //projection: "EPSG:4042",
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(79, 21)
     }
);
```

i.e. commenting out projection.

Comment: Is the scaleline generated by OpenLayers or is it a GeoServer map decoration?

Comment: It's generated by openlayers via API `OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine`

Comment: EPSG:4042 has latlong degrees, and is **no** LCC projection. You can however build a LCC projection on the same datum as EPSG:4042 uses.

Answer (score 2):

You should add parameter to map: units: "m"

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
 {
    units : 'm', // <-define units
    maxExtent: bounds,
    maxResolution: 0.10,
    //projection: "EPSG:4042",
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(79, 21)
  }
);
```